# Pass prop to Component when using React.forwardRef

Tags: reactjs

How to pass maskValue into **TextMaskCustom** and update **mask prop**.

Basically I need to mask value to be dynamic

```
import { IMaskInput } from 'react-imask';
import { OutlinedInput } from '@material-ui/core';

const TextMaskCustom = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const { onChange, ...other } = props;

    console.log(props);

    return (
        <IMaskInput
            {...other}
            mask="0[00].0[00].0[00].0[00]"
            inputRef={ref}
            onAccept={(value) => onChange({ target: { name: props.name, value } })}
        />
    );
});


<OutlinedInput
   maskvalue="0[00].0[00].0[00].0[00]"
   value={value}
   onChange={onChange}
   inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
/>
```

**Output of props**

[image]

Comment: `mask={props.maskValue}`? not sure if I understand what you want

Comment: @PedroFeltrin yes correct but `props.maskvalue` gives undefined. I tried logging the props. I have put the snapshot of it in the post

Comment: what component is `OutlinedInput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://mui.com/api/outlined-input/ you need to pass it into a specific prop called `inputProps`

Comment: thanks it works...   `inputProps={{ maskValue: '0[00].0[00].0[00].0[00]' }}`